# Jdbctemplate.query() selection process using a select query (SPRING FRAMEWORK)

Tags: spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using the SPRING jdbcTemplate to extract some data from my DB using the following piece of code :

```
jdbctemplate.query(SELECT_SQL_QUERY, new RowCallbackHandler(){
    public void processRow(resultsetRS) throws SQLException{

    // Some operations here
    } 
});
```

When I use a select query,I want to know wether this method `jdbctemplate.query()` **loads everything from the database before to process the data or loads row after another ?**

I need the answer because I am using two `SELECT` queries and the second depends of the results of the first one (the results of the operations done on the selected data), means that if the second call loads everything before doing any treatement it won't take into accound the last changes of the first call (because i'm using paralellism in my code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SELECT query executed in JDBC returns all the rows as a set.

You have to execute the first query and then execute the second one.

This is the source of (n+1) death by latency.

A better solution might be to do it in one query: You'll only have one network round trip that way.

Comment: returns all the rows as a set ? even if it concerns a large amount of data ? 10 000  row 100 000 row ... ?

Comment: Yes that's how SQL works. If your query brings back a million rows you either have to handle them or write a smarter query.

Comment: And what's the n+1 death by latency ?

Comment: Query 1 returns n rows in 1 round trip. Your code then loops over n rows and executes one query for each. That means (n+1) network round trips. Lots of latency going back & forth. A JOIN query could bring back the same info in 1 round trip.

Comment: Okay Thanx for ur answers

Comment: Looking at your other question you could write a MySQL stored procedure and do it on the database side.  No latency death that way.

Comment: The thing is, I am switching a code from PL/Sql to Java, stored procedures are going to bring me back to PL/Sql

Comment: No you're switching from Oracle to MySQL. You are correct - if you go the stored procedure route you tie yourself to one vendor. It was just an idea.

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle's stored procedure language for their relational database.  If you switch to MySQL, you'll have to port to their stored procedure language.  It's not PL/SQL.